# Django: using a premade mysql db with no relationships defined

Tags: mysql, django, foreign-keys, django-migrations

I have a mysql db with data in it and no relationships defined. What I want is to use this database in a Django project and I want it to have the relationships defined. There are fields that are supposed to be ForeignKeys but are defined as IntegerFields. So basically I want to change them to foreignKeys.

What I have:

```
company_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

What I Want:

```
company_id = models.ForeignKey('Company', on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class Inquiry(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField()
    company_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'inquiry'
```

What I am trying:

```
class Inquiry(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField()
    company_id=models.ForeignKey('Company',on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'inquiry'
```

Comment: are you trying to import your database from MySQL to Django or you have created a model and want to import tables into MySQL

Comment: I am trying to import my database from MySQL to Django.

Comment: u can use @robertHamster answer but if you want to import in specific file u can ue this command `python manage.py inspect 
db  tablename >cms/model/models.py`

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following link: [Django - Legacy Databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/legacy-databases/)

After you've created your `models.py`, you will need to do execute a `migrate`. After the first `migrate`, go into `models.py` and make the edits you need!

**EDIT/ADDITION**

Essentially:

```
python manage.py inspectdb > models.py
```

Remove `managed = False` from `class Meta:` of each model

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Treat it as if it was created by django from the beginning :)

**EDIT 2**

Again, my solution should work. The way you are trying to define the relationship isn't the way django's relationships like to be defined. To link an inquiry to a company, this should work:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50) #django automatically creates a PK/ID field
class Inquiry(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True) #null and blank params not required
```

Django will take care of establishing the MySQL relationships in the DB, that is the whole purpose of using the django ORM.

Once you have defined the fields in django, run a migration:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Django should alter the tables in your MySQL accordingly (I'm not 100% sure)

Comment: I did that but the relationships are not defined. For example a user_id should be a ForeignKey but it is defined an IntegerField. If I try to make it a ForeignKey in the models.py file and migrate. It throws the following error : (1054, "Unknown column 'inquiry.company_id_id' in 'field list'")

Comment: I would break the relationship in MySQL and re-make it in Django. Otherwise, keep `managed = False`
Another thing you can do is to just add a new field `user_fk = models.ForeignKey(...)`

Comment: But the relationships don't exist in MySQL. And that is why I am trying to make them in django

Comment: Please post a copy of your `models.py` in the question as an edit

Answer (score 0):

From the django docs on [related_name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name):

> The name to use for the relation from the related object back to this one. It’s also the default value for related_query_name (the name to use for the reverse filter name from the target model).

In the scenario you have, add the Company model, then, in the Inquiry model `ForeignKey`, specify a `related_name` field name with the Company attribute you want to link.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField()
    ...

class Inquiry(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField()         
    company_id=models.ForeignKey(to=Company, related_name="id", null=True, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'inquiry'
```